# Функция realloc вызывает Ошибку сегментирования

Tags: c, память

В функции fill_text() realloc'ом расширяю text (указатель на массив структур). Но realloc() здесь выдает ошибку (в функции fill_sent функция работает нормально). В чем может быть проблема? (принудительное приведение типа не помогает)

,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Sentence{
    char* string;
    int len;
};

int fill_sent(struct Sentence* sent){
    int i = 0, nl_counter = 0;
    char c;
    sent->string = (char*)malloc(3 * sizeof(char));
    while( (c = getchar()) != '.' && c != '?' && c != '!'){
        sent->string[i] = c;
        if(c == '\n'){
            nl_counter++;
            if (nl_counter == 2)
                return 0;
        }
        ++i;
        sent->string = realloc(sent->string, (i + 3) * sizeof(char));
    }
    sent->string[i] = '.';
    sent->string[i + 1] = '\0';
    sent->len = i + 1;
    return 1;
}

int fill_text(struct Sentence *text){
    int i = 0;
    while(fill_sent(&text[i])){
        i++;
        text = realloc(text, sizeof(struct Sentence) *  (i + 1));
    }
    return i;
    
}

void print_text(struct Sentence *text, int len){
    for(int i = 0; i < len; ++i){
        printf("\n%s\n", text[i].string);
    }
}

int main(){
    struct Sentence* text = malloc(sizeof(struct Sentence));
    int len = fill_text(text);
    print_text(text, len);    
}
```

Comment: А где вы проверяете, что возвращает `realloc`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В функции

```
int fill_text(struct Sentence *text){
    int i = 0;
    while(fill_sent(&text[i])){
        i++;
        text = realloc(text, sizeof(struct Sentence) *  (i + 1));
    }
    return i;   
}
```

вы выделенную память храните в локальной переменной. И меняете указатель локально.  А функция `main` не знает, что переданный указатель уже неликвидный.

Передавать указатель надо по-указателю :

main :

```
int len = fill_text( & text);
```

fill_text :

```
int fill_text(struct Sentence * * text){
    int i = 0;
    while(fill_sent(&(*text)[i])){
        i++;
        * text = realloc( * text, sizeof(struct Sentence) *  (i + 1));
    }
    return i;   
}
```